# CSS wrong order on align right

Tags: html, css

Consider following HTML. I want to align first `li` item to the left, and last two to the right. However, setting the right align to the last two will place the middle `li` to the right most, and the right most `li` to the middle. How can I fix this order?

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="one">left</li>
    <li class="two">right</li>
    <li class="three">right last</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li{
    float: left;
}

ul li.two,
ul li.three{
    float: right
}
```

Comment: Don't think you can do it with CSS but I may be wrong. Best bet would be to change the HTML so 'two' is last in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block` to align the li's and you can use `width` to adjust

```
​li{
   display:inline-block
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is correct, as you begin aligning the middle li to the right, so it is the first that is drawn to the right side. Then the last one follows to the right side.

I don't know any way around using two different ul-tags when using 'float'.

Answer (score 0):

A comma is missing in style defined by you in `"float: right"`. It should be `"float:right;"`

Try this

```
ul{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li{
    float: right;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

ul li.one{
    float: left;
}
```

Let me know if the issue is still there.